# conversion from Long to String[]

Tags: android, sqlite, type-conversion

i got this error :

```
The method query(String, String[], String, String[], String, String, String) in the type SQLiteDatabase is not applicable for the arguments (String, String[], String, String, null, null, null)
```

**and the code responsible:**

```
public Cursor getDomanda(String id) {
            List<categorie> categorie = new ArrayList<categorie>();

            Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_SONDAGGI,
                allCategorieColumns, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID + "=", id, null, null, null);

            cursor.moveToFirst();
            while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
              categorie categoria = cursorToCategorie(cursor);
              categorie.add(categoria);
              cursor.moveToNext();
            }
            // Make sure to close the cursor
           // cursor.close();
            return cursor;
          }
```

**on the other side:**

```
long strcategory = getIntent().getExtras().getLong("categoriaId"); 
Cursor values = datasource.getDomanda(Long.toString(strcategory));
```

what i'm doing wrong?
i need to convert the long to `String[]` but what the heck is a `String[]` ?:D
and by the way...is the query right?
i mean

```
database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_SONDAGGI,
                    allCategorieColumns, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID + "=", id, null, null, null);
```

**is**

```
select from tableSondaggi where _id = $id ?
```

Comment: Are you asking what an array is?

Comment: srsly ? what is a `String[]`?

Comment: sorry, i know arrays :D i was just a bit tired :D:D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 4th parameter must be a `String[]`, not a `String`.

You need to replace `id` by `new String[] { id }` to create an array composed of one single element (your id).

```
  Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_SONDAGGI,
            allCategorieColumns, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID + "=", new String[] { id }, null, null, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick.

```
Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_SONDAGGI,
            allCategorieColumns, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID + "=",  new String[] { id }, null, null, null);
```

BUT : Maybe reading some books about basic programming could be necessary. Arrays (`String[]` for instance) are quite useful...